# Python: What's the best way to pass a multiword string as argument

Tags: shell

So I am working on a script which could be called as:

```
python script.py OOPS Programming myfile.txt
```

Here `OOPS Programming`is a single argument which could also be a single word, e:g; `OOPS`. I know that double quotation can be used to pass a single argument, is there some better or Pythonic?

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python, it's all about the shell… If you had specific restrictions which tell you where the sentence begins and ends, you could parse this back together in Python. But the practical and most pythonic way to handle this is to actually pass it as one argument, for which the shell requires you to use quotes.

Comment: I've removed the `python` tag and added `shell`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an XY problem that is really about how to quote strings in shells, which is much too broad unless further clarified.

Comment: Are you guaranteed to always have a two word argument there? if so, you can list slice the `argv`. Double quotes have nothing to do with pythonic-ness, that's how shell deals with space separated values.

Comment: Not sure how is it not related to Python. I have no issue if it's related with shell but as a python programmer it's also needed to know how to deal such situation in Python.

Answer (score 0):

To pass `OOPS Programming` as a single argument, put quotes around it:

```
python script.py 'OOPS Programming' myfile.txt
```

In the shell, arguments to a command are separated by white space. When you execute any program, the string containing the arguments is split on white space and passed to the program as a list of arguments.

The quotes prevent the shell from splitting this part of the string.

Without the quotes, there is no way for the shell to distinguish between the space between "OOPS" and "Programming" and the one between "Programming" and "myfile.txt", so each word becomes a separate argument in the list.

With the quotes, your Python program sees the string "OOPS Programming" as a single argument, so you don't need to anything special to access it all in one go.

Here's a simple python script to demonstrate:

```
import sys

for index, arg in enumerate(sys.argv):
    print(index, arg)
```

From the shell, called with and without quotes:

```
$ python3 script.py OOPS Programming myfile.txt
0 script.py
1 OOPS
2 Programming
3 myfile.txt
$ python3 script.py 'OOPS Programming' myfile.txt
0 script.py
1 OOPS Programming
2 myfile.txt
```